# How to find value for specific dates for a process stored in table

Tags: performance, pivot, query, query-performance

I have a table called as tab where we store all the process running on machine in below format

```
proc_name     start_date     Duration
proc1         24-Jul-18      0:0
proc2         24-Jul-18      0:0
proc3         24-Jul-18      0:0
proc4         24-Jul-18      0:0
proc1         25-Jul-18      0:01
proc2         25-Jul-18      0:02
proc3         25-Jul-18      0:04
proc4         25-Jul-18      0:03
proc1         26-Jul-18      01:0
proc2         26-Jul-18      02:0
proc3         26-Jul-18      02:0
proc4         26-Jul-18      04:0
```

I want to see output as per below format:

```
Proc_name   Date1  Duration(of date1) Date2 Duration(of date2) Date3 Duration(of date3) 
proc1       24_jul-18  0:0            25-Jul-18 0:01           26-Jul-18 01:0
proc2       24_jul-18  0:0            25-Jul-18 0:02           26-Jul-18 02:0
proc3       24_jul-18  0:0            25-Jul-18 0:04           26-Jul-18 02:0
proc4       24_jul-18  0:0            25-Jul-18 0:03           26-Jul-18 04:0
```

Comment: Is your `duration` limited to max. 24 hours by any chance? This would allow a simpler solution. Please always provide your version of Postgres and a table definition showing actual data types and constraints (`CREATE TABLE` statement).

Comment: Oh, I was assuming PostgreSQL, but you didn't actually say so. What is your RDBMS?

Comment: My Bad...yes this is RDBMS...not a postgres...

Comment: RDBMS is the general term: "Relational DataBase Management System". The question is, *which* RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Details will depend on the database engine, but I think `Pivot` is the key search term you want.  An approach that can probably be adapted for use with many database engines is described on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846007/sql-query-to-pivot-a-column-using-case-when.  SQL Server has had a `PIVOT` operator since version 2008: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot.

Martin